# SQL - Get or Create in foreign table in one insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have two tables

```
Session
- Id
- UserId
- CodeId (foreign key to Code.Id)
```

and

```
Code
- Id
- Text (string of 50 - 100 characters)
```

Of course I could do the following:

1. Try get the Id from Code
2. if this returns empty insert a new row and grab the Id
3. Insert the Session

Together you will get something similar like this:

```
DECLARE @codeId INT;

SET @codeId = (SELECT Id FROM Code WHERE [Text] = @code);

IF ( @codeId IS NULL )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Code ([Text]) VALUES (@code)
    SET @codeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

INSERT INTO Session (UserId, codeId) VALUES(@userId, @codeId)
```

- is it also possible to do this in a bit more efficient call?
- should I be concerned about race conditions?

Disclaimers:
This will be called *a lot* on a production site with a large amount of users and in this environment it is already proven that performance matters.

**Extra notes**

- There will be a Unique Index on `Code.Text`
- I expect millions of rows in `Session`
- I expect about 50.000 to 200.000 rows in `Code`

Comment: Roughly how many rows do you expect in Code? Will you have indexes on text? Can that index be unique?

Comment: I recommend adding `nolock` to your select `(SELECT Id FROM Code WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [Text] = @code);`

Comment: Hi @SerkanArslan, thanks for your message - can you elaborate why?

Comment: @DirkBoer It prevents waits on the select if Code table has any lock because of the insert. And it looks possible because of potential session count.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one - I'd definitely create a test harness to verify your assumptions here.

The first thing I'd do is reverse the order - if you have "millions" of children, and "hundreds of thousands" of parents, there's a good chance your children already have matching parent rows.

So, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Session (UserId, codeId) 
SELECT @userId, [Text]
FROM Code
where [Text] = @code

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
begin
    INSERT INTO Code ([Text]) VALUES (@code)
    SET @codeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Session (UserId, codeId) VALUES(@userId, @codeId)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is going to be a much more efficient method, assuming you have the right indexes.

Should you be concerned about race conditions?  Well, with your given code, then "yes", but this is easily addressed.  Start with a unique index so the database enforces uniqueness on `Text`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_code_text ON Code(Text);
```

Then, the code should look like:

```
DECLARE @codeId INT;

SET @codeId = (SELECT Id FROM Code WHERE [Text] = @code);

IF ( @codeId IS NULL )
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Code ([Text]) VALUES (@code)
        SET @codeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- you can check or just assume that the issue the unique constraint
END CATCH;

INSERT INTO Session (UserId, codeId)
    VALUES (@userId, @codeId);
```

The `TRY`/`CATCH` block handles the race conditions.